# calculating probabilty of variable belonging to a probabilistic range

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose there are two random continuous variables $x$ and $y$ always non-negative, i.e. they do not assume negative values at all. They have their density functions given, $p_x$ and $p_y$. How do i compute the probability:
$prob(\,x \,\,\, s.t. \,\,\, -y\leq x-y\leq 0)$? If y had been a constant variable then the probability could be computed very easily as : $\int \limits_{0}^y p_x\,dx $. But when $y$ is also a random variable, then how to proceed? For simplicity one can define another random variable, $z=x-y$ with its associated density as $p_z$ for this question but it is not necessary. Then you can say find $prob(\,z \,\,\, s.t. \,\,\, -y\leq z\leq 0)$. Please give full mathematical details and references as i have only started taking a probability course.

Comment: What is     $y $? If $X,Y$ are nonnegative then what do $y,x$ have to do with $X,Y$?

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable (which seems to be the case, judging from your question, then $P(X \le 0)=0.$

Comment: @DavidK I had written the question a bit wrong. I have edited it. please see.

Comment: @zoli I have improved the language of the question. in the entire question there are only 2 variables, x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things straight, it is clearer to refer to the random variables themselves as $X$ and $Y$, and their PDFs as $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ (that is, $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables in the PDFs).

Assuming that $X$ has an atomless distribution (that is, there is no value $x$ for which $P(X = x) > 0$ strictly), $X-Y > -Y$ almost surely.  The straightforward approach then is to progressively uncondition.  You have stated already how to proceed when $Y = y$:

$$
P(X-Y < 0 \mid Y = y) = \int_{x=0}^y f_X(x) \, dx
$$

To determine the unconditional probability $P(X-Y < 0)$, we use the PDF of $Y$ to uncondition:

$$
P(X-Y < 0) = \int_{y=0}^\infty f_Y(y) P(X-Y < 0 \mid Y = y) \, dy
           = \int_{y=0}^\infty f_Y(y) \left(\int_{x=0}^y f_X(x) \, dx\right) \, dy
$$

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y $ independent?

Comment: Ha!  Good question.  I've assumed they are (and OP's notion of the *conditional* probability for a given $Y = y$ suggests that they are as well).  If they aren't, OP may have to specify the dependence.